# How to make an animated button in Apple WatchKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, watchkit

I'd like to make a button with animation in WatchKit, but it seems I can't find a way to modify `WKInterfaceButton` or drag an image into button in storyboard. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After some research I found the solution, it's pretty simple but easily ignored :)

First, drag a button into a scene created in storyboard.

Second, select button, modify its property `content` from `Text` to `Group`. If you can't find `content` property, click the `Attributes Inspector` button at top right of your screen, it looks like a breakpoint button or a down arrow with a bar.

[image]

Now you can control group created inside your button. You need to add a reference of this `WKInterfaceGroup` inside your controller code. Here is an example:

```
@interface AAPLButtonDetailController()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfaceGroup *buttonGroup;   
@end


@implementation AAPLButtonDetailController

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        // Initialize variables here.
        // Configure interface objects here.
        [_buttonGroup setBackgroundImageNamed:@"Bus"];
        [_buttonGroup startAnimating];
    }

    return self;
}
```

So the button animation will be played after scene initialized. Remember only frame animation is supported for now, all frames in one animation should be named like "Bus0.png", "Bus1.png"....

[image]

Hope this can help :)

Comment: This is really good. I'm using animated buttons subtlety all throughout my watch app for nice effect. Also if you don't care if your animation loops infinitely you can also set an animation as a background of a group. Lots of little tricks. I'm sure we'll be able to work a lot with core graphics with Apple Watch 2's new processor.

Answer (score 1):

Reck's post worked for me in instances that I needed to control the repeat count or duration. If you simply want to start or stop an animation for a button, the following works for me, where twoButton is a WKInterfaceButton and I have a set of images name Bus0@2x.png, Bus1@2x.png, etc.

```
- (void)startButtonAnimating
{
    // This works, but can't control repeat counts or duration
    [self.twoButton setBackgroundImageNamed:@"Bus"];
    // But you can stop after a delay by setting background image nil
    [self performSelector:@selector(stopGroupButtonAnimating) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.5];
}

- (void)stopButtonAnimating
{
    [self.twoButton setBackgroundImage:nil];
}
```